# PLSQL: CLOB data returns ORA:06502

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, clob

Querying a clob column through native dynamic sql is not working as expected, does dbms_lob.substr has any  limit while its used in native dynamic sql? Any suggestions on how can I run with dbms_lob.substr(column_name,32767,1)

Note - car_model is fetched within the procedure and set with the in clause of dynamic sql.

**Here is the code which throws error:**

```
create or replace procedure test (id in varchar2,
                                  result out sys_refcursor)
as
dyn varchar2(32000):=NULL;
car_model varchar2(32000) :=NULL;
begin
dyn:='Select a.id, dbms_lob.substr(b.description,32767,1) from table a 
join table b
on a.id=b.id
and dbms_lob.substr(b.description,32767,1) in (select dbms_lob.substr(c.detail,32767,1) from table c
where c.make in ('||car_model||'))';
open result for dyn;
END test;
```

**if dbms_lob.substr is reduced to 4000 as shown below it runs fine but trims the characters to 4k**

```
  create or replace procedure test (id in varchar2,
                                          result out sys_refcursor)
        as
        dyn varchar2(32000):=NULL;
        car_model varchar2(32000) :=NULL:
        begin
        dyn:='Select a.id, dbms_lob.substr(b.description,4000,1) from table a 
        join table b
        on a.id=b.id
        and dbms_lob.substr(b.description,4000,1) in (select dbms_lob.substr(c.detail,4000,1) 
        from table c
        where c.make in ('||car_model||'))';
        open result for dyn;
        END test;
```

Comment: The Oracle SQL `varchar2` type is limited to 4000 bytes, so it can't handle 32K strings. I would expect this to be a problem in static SQL as well.

Comment: yes  @WilliamRobertson it throws error in static sql as well but I am running it in plsql where it should hold 32k I believe, is that understanding wrong

Comment: The failing statement is SQL, even though it is being called from PL/SQL. There's only one kind of SQL in the database.

Comment: Ahh ok , thanks for the wisdom @WilliamRobertson got that, but how do we handle clobs to suffice the above scenario then. There is another point to add when I try to select a column from table a which is also clob data type it returns perfectly, then it should also fail right . Here is the code` Select c.id, dbms_lob.substr(c.details,32000,1) from table c; `

Comment: @Migs - it depends how long the actual values are; what is `max(length(details))`? Also, you need to use substr for the in/join, which could give you some false matched (depending in data); but you can just return the full description in the select list - you don't have to substr it there.